# how to cite several enteries in tufte-book

Tags: bibtex, citing, tufte

I am using tufte-book for my document and I am trying to cite several entries in one \cite command but what I get is only one number for all the citations and also the citations are listed one after each other connected without numbers in the side notes. Any idea how to solve this?

```
\documentclass[titlepage, a4paper, twoside, justified]{tufte-book}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}

The long-range order in these materials and the interplay between their $\pi$-electronic structure and geometrical structure have given rise to a developing field of research\cite{Gershenson2006,Jurchescu2004,Su04}. 
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{mylibrary} 

\end{document}
```

And

```
\bibitem{Gershenson2006}
M.~E. Gershenson, V.~Podzorov, and A.~F. Morpurgo.
\newblock {Colloquium : Electronic transport in single-crystal organic
  transistors}.
\newblock {\em Rev. Mod. Phys.}, 78(3):973--989, sep 2006.

\bibitem{Jurchescu2004}
O.~D. Jurchescu, J.~Baas, and T.~T.~M. Palstra.
\newblock {Effect of impurities on the mobility of single crystal pentacene}.
\newblock {\em Appl. Phys. Lett.}, 84(16):3061--3063, 2004.

\bibitem{Su04}
{Sundar, V. C.}, {Zaumseil, J.}, {Podzorov, V.}, {Menard, E.}, {Willett, R.
  L.}, {Someya, T.}, {Gershenson, M. E.}, and {Rogers, J. A.}
\newblock {Elastomeric transistor stamps: reversible probing of charge
  transport in organic crystals.}
\newblock {\em Science}, 303(5664):1644--1646, mar 2004.
```

Another question is how removes the citations from side notes or maybe just make them more compact like showing only the journal information?!

[image]Thanks in advance!

By the way, I am using Texmaker.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use subsequent `\cite` commands.

```
The long-range order in these materials and the interplay between their 
$\pi$-electronic structure and geometrical structure have given rise to a 
developing field of research.\cite{Gershenson2006}\cite{Jurchescu2004}\cite{Su04}
```

As a sidenote ;), you might want to put the period before the citations.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but how do I get numbers in a compact form like for example [1-5] instead of what I get with citing each as you also suggested and it appears like 1,2,3,4,5 and if I have more citations, it just looks not nice! I have tried changing the style or playing with the citing format but no success since I am not a professional in latex. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: What about shortening the citations on the margin like showing just the journal information?